# Chrome devtools not logging "undefined" anymore?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, reactjs

So, since a few days, my `chrome developer tools`/`console` won't output *any* `undefined` errors or `Uncaught ReferenceError` in some cases.
The script *just stops* without any indication, and I *don't* have `pause on exceptions` on, and there's *no* breakpoints.

Trying to call an `undefined` function `foo()` for example:

[image]

I have the filter on `all` so I'm not filtering anything.

I've reset the settings via `Settings->General->'Restore defaults and reload'`

I've tried disabling *all* extensions, but no difference.

I've tried a new user in chrome, still nothing

I've tried using `"use strict"` in my code, nothing.

I'm pretty sure this has something to do with `reactjs`, where `foo()` is not defined anywhere, but try to call it like the above screenshot. I had the same issue inside `mixins`.

Strangest thing is, that not all reactClasses have this problem. Also I've been through version 14.x to 14.7.

I've even tried **copying** a reactClass/Component which **does** output an error `Uncaught ReferenceError` as I'm trying in the above screenshot, but just give it another name (ie assign to different variable and export as separate module). And you guessed it, then the above screenshot occurs, no error, **For the same exact code** ?

I know, you're probably thinking I'm doing something terribly wrong, but how does a **copy** behave differently?

I think the above image indicates that something very strange is happening here. There must be a logical explanation, but I can't find any.

This is extremely frustrating, and I'm at a loss how to fix this/what the cause is.

It also doesn't matter where I put `foo()`, whether it's in `render` or in `componentWillMount` or any other method. And the worst is, if it's in `componentDidMount` I don't even notice, except that the component doesn't react or update anymore.

Upon further investigation it seems this problem only occurs on the **first render** of the whole component hierarchy...
This is new to me, it's as if the initial render has to be flawless and otherwise it will just halt without informing the developer.

On the upside, I now have to pay extra attention to the coherence of my code ;P. But truly, I can't really work like this.

Comment: Is this Chrome specific? Have you tried in other browsers?

Comment: Whoever voted to close this question because it's off-topic, please read the close reason again - "unless [the question] *directly involve tools used primarily for programming*"

Comment: @Matt, yes, I disabled it, as you can see in the screenshot @Kruga , I've tried firefox, and it doesn't output an error as well. I tagged `devtools` because I wasn't sure before. I will remove it.

Comment: And to emphasize, it only seems to occur on the **first render**. As i found out later while composing the question.

Comment: I have noticed the same behavior yesterday while debugging in Chrome. I don't think it is you - I think there is a bug in the latest build TBH.